# Updating images in GridView with custom adapter every 10 sec

Tags: android, listview, gridview, picasso, custom-adapter

I have `Fragment` in my `Activity`. In this fragment I show `GridView` which is populated with custom adapter. I'm using Picasso library to dowload images from web. The key problem is that I don't know how to update images in my `GridView` every 10 sec (pictire on server changes every 10 sec, buyt links stay static).

I'v already try using `Handler` and gridview.invalidate() in fragment and it's not help me :(

Any help how to properly update content of listview (without scrolling to begin or with it) will be appreciatted.

**PictureAdapter.java**
public class PicturesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
private List<Camera> cameras;

public PicturesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Camera> cameras) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.cameras = cameras;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cameras.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return cameras.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PictureHolder pictureHolder;

    if (convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_item_layout,parent,false);

        pictureHolder = new PictureHolder();
        pictureHolder.pictureItemImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture_item_image);
        pictureHolder.pictureItemTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture_item_text);

        convertView.setTag(pictureHolder);
    } else {
        pictureHolder = (PictureHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(cameras.get(position).getCameraSysInfoIMGUrl())
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(pictureHolder.pictureItemImageView);
    //Log.i("drew",cameras.get(position).getCameraSysInfoIMGUrl());
    pictureHolder.pictureItemTextView.setText(cameras.get(position).getCameraName());

    return convertView;
}

static class PictureHolder{
    ImageView pictureItemImageView;
    TextView pictureItemTextView;
}

public String getCameraId(int position) {
    return cameras.get(position).getCameraId();
}
```

}

Comment: Android provides the SyncAdapter pattern which  allows you to automatically sync. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/

Comment: You need to evict `Picasso`'s cache every 10 seconds.

Comment: @dextor can you pls explain how to do this, cos I cant find this on http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Picasso now has declarative cache controls. For instance, you can specify something like

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
  .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
  .into(imageView);
```

This forces Picasso to re-fetch the image from the network.

Comment: Ok, I ll try this solution now. Do I need any handlers in, my fragment?

Comment: If I use .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE) and .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE) with handler which set new adapter to Gridview, obviously I see full redraw of all GridView. Is it possible to force notifyDataSetChanged or something else to update, not full redraw content of gridView?

Comment: You don't need to set the adapter to the GridView. Why would you?

Comment: I have List of Objects which contain all information like links, additional info, etc. This List generated at first run and used at this session.